# How do I connect a VB.net program to a access database and run it on 2 different PCs.

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a windows application written in VB.net. After finishing it I'll setup the program in more than one pc. I want to connect the program in all PCs to one database in another PC using Microsoft Access, and I also want to limit the level of access of the users to the database in my program.

How can I do it? Many thanks.

Comment: Please be more specific with which part of this task you are having trouble with.

Comment: do i need to use asp.net or deploy my program to web application to work on one database ? does access enough for such demands or i should turn my database to sql?merci

Comment: I would definitely recommend SQL Over access, if that is an option. Access will handle multiple connections, but only with small loads and few connections. Since it's not client/server based, you risk conflicts causing corruption. You don't need a web based application to share an access DB. you can just put the MDB on a network share and point the connection strings on all clients to that common network share location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access is capable of handling multiple users, however once you get over 3 or 4 concurrent users you will start to notice that MS Access doesn't scale well. Access is designed for the professional but not an enterprise.

Microsoft SQL Server (Express edition is free - upto 4GB space) is designed for a large number of concurrent users.

**I also want to limit the level of access of the users to the database in my program.**

You can use folder Permissions if you wish to restrict access to the file. Personally in my old VB6 apps that used MS Access I called the file db.resources rather than db.mdb. This is because a.resources file cant be downloaded if it is hosted online (ref DotNetNuke) and also so people dont know which program to open the file in.

If you need role based security you need a enterprise level database such as SQL Server.

**I want to connect the program in all PCs to one database in another PC using Microsoft Access.**

Here is how you can have two computers share the same database.

a. Choose the main PC that will host the database

b. Host the database in a folder that is shared to the other users

c. Physically go over to the PC that isn't hosting the database, create a text fileon the desktop.

d. Rename the file extension from `.txt` to `.udl` and press enter

e. Double clcik the udl file and enter these settings and navigate to the shared folder that hosts the shared database:

[image: UDL file connection stirng]

f. Once the Test Connection is successful, close the Data Link Properties window.

g. Right click the UDL file on the desktop and choose Open With and open with notepad

h. You will see your connection string:

> [oledb]   ; Everything after this line is an OLE DB initstring
> Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data
> Source=\\PCName\c$\temp\Database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False

i. Set the second pc to use the networked connection string.

Answer (score 2):

Access is perfectly capable to handle 2 users connecting to the same database. However this is not the main strenght of Ms-Access. So, if you plan to grow the user base it's better to start from the beginning with SqlServer Express (or MySql).

You don't need to use asp-net for this scenario if the user are on the same local network.
You are only required to prepare a valid connection string to identify the network location where you install the database. Of course, the PC hosting the database should share the network location and give read/write permissions to all users requiring the access to the database. (This could be the most complicated part depending on where you share the database)

Comment: and can i limit the level of accessibility to the data for different pc in my local net this way?

Comment: No, it's a whole or nothing affair. In access 2003 there was the Workgroup Administrator utility that could give you a bit of security control on your tables, but in the latest version it seems that Microsoft has done its best to hide this functionality, but I'm no more an expert now, I have switched away from Access since 2007 version

Comment: For the security related part, just found [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/accessdev/thread/20cea8ee-7d87-49f6-9c35-3ce721a389c1)