# How to connect C# Winform Project to the XAMPP MySQL server in LAN?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, xampp

I have wrote a simple program which uses MySQL db server of XAMPP. Program works fine when I connect to 'localhost':

[image]

But when I try connect a MySQL db from another computer (in my LAN):

[image]

it gives below error:

[image]

But I can connect to that 'phpmyadmin' from browser:

[image]

(or Can it be that the computers which I'm testing are domain members ?)

Comment: Create a text file with a UDL extension. Check you can connnect from that DataLink utility. If not resort to TCP pings to check the dB is listening on the port. Ensure you can ping the dB address.

Comment: sorry but I'm so expert (at least I do not know how to do it). Is there any link to learn or try ?

Comment: Just see the pictures here and do the same thing for MySQL, https://stackoverflow.com/a/11068411/495455 Does it work using the DataLink Properties window?

Comment: From your machine, can you `telnet 10.10.22.147 3306`. Your phpmyadmin can connect probably because its local host (running on the same machine as mysql) if your machine cannot connect I would suspect firewall on the remote machine is blocking, or mysql is blocking connections from non local host. Telnet is not installed by default; you have to use Add Windows Features to install it

Comment: @CaiusJard, thanks for your advice. Actually problem was mysql is blocking non local host connections, I changed bind to any host it worked. If you post the answer (how to unblock non localhost connections on xampp), I will accept the answer.

Comment: To some extent, your test with phpmyadmin is a "red-herring".  That tool is running on the _remote_ machine, then connecting _locally_ to mysqld.  A better test would be to run phpmyadmin on your host, then connect via 10... to mysqld.

Comment: @RickJames, could you refer me to anywhere to try it out (below method worked on me, and I thought that is the normal way)

Comment: There's also the need for a `GRANT` to allow the user access across the network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the problem was, MySQL server settings has set to work only for local connections (by default):

[image]

So, then I uncommented the second line and chanded to:

[image]

And it worked. '**127.0.0.1**' means **localhost** and '**0.0.0.0**' means **any host**

Answer (score 2):

Please check your Firewall on the remote machine. It might block the mysql connection and has an exception rule for HTTP Ports, thats why phpMyAdmin is reachable.

Comment: I turned off all networks firewall but it didn't work